# Increase thickness of a 'line' in text environment

Tags: symbols, color

I am using the following code to generate color line to use a legend of a graph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,soul}

\begin{document}

\boldsymbol{\textcolor{blue}{\scalebox{1.5}[1.0]{\( - \)}}}

\end{document}
```

How to increase the thickness of this color line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using `\rule` instead of a math minus `-`. It's defined as `\rule[<raise>]{<width>}{<thickness>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{blue}{$-$}

\textcolor{blue}{\rule[.5ex]{1em}{.4pt}}

\textcolor{blue}{\rule[.5ex]{1em}{1pt}}

\textcolor{blue}{\rule[.5ex]{1em}{2pt}}

\end{document}
```